# Get JSON Facebook Graph API User Info with jQuery

Tags: jquery, json, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to use the graph API to get just some basic info about a user no need for authorization by the user just the public details. I am trying to use jQuery and the .getJSON to get the data and parse it but I am having a hard time trying to figure out how to access the key value pairs I want.

I want to have something like

```
var fburl = "http://graph.facebook.com/USER/callback=?"

$.getJSON(fburl, function(data){
  $.each(data, function(i,item){
     var name = item.user["name"];
     $("#profile").append("<h3>"name"</h3>");
  });
});
```

ive tried things like item.name and a bunch of other what I figured to be potential syntax options but still getting undefined.

Is there anything wrong with this approach I only really have experience using JSON with twitter API which works fine with the above approach.

When I console log data I get something like this

```
first_name: "First"
gender: "male"
id: "8977344590"
etc...
name: "Full Name"
```

Comment: what do you get in the `data` string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't return an array, but an object. You don't need to be looping over anything.

You can just get the name straight from the object:

```
$.getJSON(fburl, function(data){
     var name = data["name"];
     $("#profile").append("<h3>"+name+"</h3>"); 
});
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/niklasvh/Wm9M3/

PS. you had a syntax error with `$("#profile").append("<h3>"+name+"</h3>");`as well (you forgot the `+` around `name`)

Comment: Thanks I just missed that syntax error truncating my code for the example

Comment: Can you help me if the URL is something like this one
https://graph.facebook.com/?ids=http://www.bloggerever.com/2013/10/how-to-prevent-function-to-get-default.html

And I want to display number of shares.Please help

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `jsonP` for cross domain issues:

```
$.get(fburl, function(data){
    console.log(data);
    alert(data.name);
},'jsonp');
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/34m9J/

Comment: $.getJSON uses `jsonp` if the url includes the string "callback=?"