# How to use data from Facebook FQL results

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, facebook, facebook-fql

I am trying to output an FQL result and show it through HTML.

What I would really like to achieve is to show the result of this FQL query:

[`https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=SELECT+id,text+FROM+comment+WHERE+object_id=10152196563766729+ORDER+BY+time+DESC+limit+5`](https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=SELECT%20id,text%20FROM%20comment%20WHERE%20object_id=10152196563766729%20ORDER%20BY%20time%20DESC%20limit%205)

and output it with HTML, I think this will need jQuery to get this done but I can't find any tutorial. I hope someone can help me achieving this.

Comment: [Google?](https://www.google.fr/search?q=read+facebook+api+data+jquery&rlz=1C1CHFX_frFR547FR547&oq=read+facebook+api+data+jquery&aqs=chrome..69i57.3532j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8) + possible duplicate of [Get JSON Facebook Graph API User Info with jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6431576/get-json-facebook-graph-api-user-info-with-jquery)

Comment: hi i tried this solution but i dont know why it doesnt work http://jsfiddle.net/EVtyL

Comment: That's because you forgot to add jQuery. Working solution below.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery's [**getJSON**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) method can load JSON-encoded data for you.

```
<div id="messages"></div>

<script>
var fburl = "https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=SELECT+id,text+FROM+comment+WHERE+object_id=606001936131241+ORDER+BY+time+DESC+limit+5&format=json";

$.getJSON(fburl, function (data) {
    $.each(data, function (i, item) {
        $("#messages").append(item.text + "<br />");
    });
}, 'jsonp');
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/EVtyL/2/